# Restore from CCC or Time Machine?

Tags: macos, restore

I'm getting a replacement Macbook Pro today. I just made a complete backup with Carbon Copy Cloner, and I also have a full Time Machine backup.

Which should I use -- Time Machine backup or CCC -- and how? I want to avoid having to reinstall software and zshell settings and so on as much as possible.

Comment: Please add some informations to your question. Is it 1:1 replacement (like MacBookPro11,5 for MacBookPro11,5)? Does your Mac contain a lot of files because you are e.g. a developer? Migration doesn't work very well then in Yosemite!

Comment: Thanks @klanomath, theoretically it's the exact same machine, but the answers here have helped me think about other scenarios. I'm trying to get in front of a recovery I'll do later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Machine would be the most reliable of the two.

CCC is brilliant for cloning to the same hardware, but it's not really meant to cross to newer hardware, as it has no 'installer' process to prepare for the new hardware/OS drivers.

However, a better option may be ...
You can migrate directly from the old Mac to the new, as part of the "welcome to your new Mac " introduction, if both can be on the network at the same time.

Comment: Sorry! I should've specified. Hardware will be the same, I'm expecting. Either Apple will repair my problem (USB port issue) and wipe the hard drive, or they'll replace the computer. [ignoring the possibility that they fix the problem without either of these two, but I'm quite confident that restoring will be necessary. Also ignoring the possibility that they hand me a newer computer]

Comment: If you're certain it's identical hardware, then the CCC clone could be fine. I'm still tempted to migrate though, for checks & balances. Either direct or TM.

Comment: Seeing your comments on the other answer that some things were excluded from TM, then I'm even more towards 'live' migrate from one machine to the other, as they then won't be excluded.

Comment: @Tetsujin Migration would require the second machine (original) to still be intact, which it appears the OP is concerned it won't be once its received back from Apple. I'd also say that a migration would work best alongside TM if available

Comment: Yes, agree @smoooosher - it wasn't apparent initially [or more accurately, I didn't grok ] that the 2 machines would not be side by side

Comment: @smoooosher yeah, I could aware accepted answer to either of you. Thanks both for the help!

Comment: Turns out the machine never got replaced, so I never got to test either hypothesis

Answer (score 3):

Time Machine would be your best route. Boot the new computer up holding Command + R and then in the Recovery utility, select "Restore from Time Machine backup" - assuming it is a full backup, it should work OK.

Comment: Thanks! What does "assuming it is a full backup" refer to? The only options I've set on Time Machine are to exclude a few directories like Google Drive and Dropbox.

Comment: Please add some pros and cons. As it's standing now it's just a useless statement

Comment: @klanomath Time Machine is the official Apple utility and would be your best option to receive support on as it is an Apple-supported product which has been tested on Apple systems by Apple. Third-party software, while I am sure has gone through rigorous testing by that company, sometimes have quirks, etc about them which Apple cannot provide support for. As it stands, it would be YMMV - some people choose one, some people choose the other. I recommend TM. And "assuming a full backup" is if you hadn't excluded any necessary directories, which some people do to save space on the backup.

Comment: And @klanomath I think it's unfair to say it is a useless statement. The OP asked which tool and how, not why. I clarified above, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them have their pros and cons and it becomes a opinionated question.

In my experiences, I got the feeling that the CCC might be the faster option compared to TM, having just restored ±680GB over a 12hour timespan ffrom 7200RPM HDD over SATA 6GB to striped Fusion drives.

Comment: Speed. Ugh, I forgot about that. Well, CCC just backed up the whole thing in 3 hours, so I imagine that restore won't be too bad

Answer (score 1):

The 2023 answer is use either, whatever your current backup strategy is using.

CCC6 [supports](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/i-want-clone-my-entire-hard-drive-new-hard-drive-or-new-machine#dont_install_older_os_versions) using the backup as a source for Migration Assistant when restoring to a new machine.

As the CCC6 standard backup [does not backup](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/cloning-macos-system-volumes-apple-software-restore) (just like Time Machine doesn't) the system volume in macOS 11 and subsequent versions (bootable backups can be done but not recommended by Bombich), the process relies on the standard macOS install first, then choose the CCC backup as the migration source.